# Visual Studio 2022 debugging string visualizer watch magnifying glass not appearing in Blazor projects

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, visual-studio-2022

I have the latest Visual Studio 2022 to date (17.5.5) installed.  When debugging a Blazor WASM project, the watch windows' text visualizer magnifying glass icon does not appear during a debug session (so we can't view JSON or XML views of data in Blazor).

[image]

(Expected behaviour described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/string-visualizer-dialog-box?view=vs-2022)

I find that the magnifying glass doesn't appear in watch window, quick watch or hovering over variables.  In other non-Blazor projects the string visualizer magnifying glass icon appears and the function works fine.

Is this a bug, is there a solution or is this to be expected?  It seems like a big omission for Blazor projects.  Do we really need to Console.WriteLine everything?  Or can we get a better debugging experience with Blazor?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your watches look like? I find that sometimes the Watch window behaves weird and getting that magnifying class to appear can be finicky.

Comment: Image added - I've added a red square where the magnifying glass normally appears (it appears in non-Blazor projects)

Comment: It almost looks like a grey box is present there, slightly different in color. Weird. Sounds stupid, but have you tried clicking in that spot ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I had tried that - clicking the empty gap does nothing.  (It appears OK in other projects).

Comment: Which browser are you using for debugging? Did you try to reset the Window layout?

Comment: Various browsers are in use no impact.  Reset windows layout does not fix.

Comment: I have just accepted that this is a limitation in the current user experience. I add debug and trace outputs to the code to assist with debugging which feels a bit old-school but it works. I expect in the future they will improve this.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSchaller - it's good to know that I'm not the only one with this issue.